# How can we implement heatmap?

Tags: android, google-maps, visualization, heatmap, user-experience

I'm developing an Android app and I want to track the usage patterns of my users to identify areas of the app that are being used the most. I've heard that a heatmap can be a good way to visualize this data, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my app.

Specifically, I'm interested in identifying usage patterns of newer users, who may be less familiar with the app's features and may need more guidance. I want to use the heatmap to identify areas of the app that newer users are using the most, so I can improve the user experience in those areas.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to implement a heatmap in an Android app to track usage patterns of newer users? Are there any libraries or APIs that would be useful for this task? Any tips on how to collect and process usage data for the heatmap would also be appreciated.

Thank you!

I've done some initial research on implementing heatmaps in Android apps and I've found that the Google Maps Android API provides a heatmap utility that can be used to display usage data. However, I'm not sure how to collect and process the usage data to create the heatmap.

Specifically, I've looked into using the Android UsageStatsManager API to collect usage data for my app, but I'm not sure how to convert this data into the format required by the heatmap utility. I'm also not sure how to filter the usage data to only include data from newer users.

Ideally, I would like to collect usage data for a set period of time (e.g. one week) and display the heatmap for that period of time. I'm hoping to identify areas of the app that are being used the most by newer users, so I can improve the user experience in those areas.

Any guidance on how to collect and process usage data for the heatmap, as well as any tips on how to filter the data for newer users, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Android Maps Utility library includes a heatmap functionality that you can use out-of-the-box:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/heatmap